# why does jenkins not substitute the version number

Tags: java, jenkins, maven-3

I have a small question about building a java application.

I have the parent application, which builds fine. But, when I try to add a submodule to the parent. the submodule will not build properly. The jenkins pipeline hangs trying to download an artefact where the url contains a variable and not the actual value.... ?

```
15:16:18  [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
15:16:18  [INFO] Downloading from nexus: http://nexus.co/repository/testpackage/egsframework/es-pom-root/$%7Begsframework.version%7D/es-pom-root-$%7Begsframework.version%7D.pom
```

which should be

```
15:16:18  [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
15:16:18  [INFO] Downloading from testpackage: http://nexus.co/repository/testpackage/egsframework/es-pom-root/0.0.1/es-pom-root-0.0.1.pom
```

in the submodule there is no mention of anything from the parent project, other than the parent tag...

```
<parent>
    <groupId>egsframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>es-pom-root</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
```

Is there something I am missing here?

Ta,

X

Comment: is the parent is not under you control? It looks like it misses properties. We probably need to view more maven output, and maybe more of the poms

Comment: In Maven 3 and earlier, you cannot use a property like `${egsframework.version}`  for the parent version. I think they plan on making that possible in Maven 4, but I'm not sure.

Comment: If you add a module in a multi module build that should have the same version usually as the all other modules and the parent.. .if you like to define the version via a property you must follow https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html (That works in Maven 3 requirement minimum 3.2.5 but use 3.8.X or 3.9.X)